# Firefox - Prevent users from adding exceptions

Tags: firefox, browser

Everything I've found on this topic is related to bypassing the exception adding process or automating it.  This is not what I want.

What I want to do is NOT allow users to add exceptions AT ALL, specifically for self-signed or untrusted certs from potentially dodgy sites, but regardless of the reason, I don't want them to even have the option of adding an exception.

Is this possible?

Kind regards,

R